# microsoft graph api azure-active-directory Connection returned HTTP code: 400 with message: Bad Request

Tags: azure-active-directory

microsoft graph api azure-active-directory Connection returned HTTP code: 400 with message: Bad Request

getToken code:

```java
IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca =ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(CLIENT_ID, credential).authority(AUTHORITY).build();
        IAuthenticationResult result;
        try {
            SilentParameters silentParameters = SilentParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(SCOPE)).build();
            // try to acquire token silently. This call will fail since the token cache does not
            // have a token for the application you are requesting an access token for
            result = cca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex.getCause() instanceof MsalException) {
                ClientCredentialParameters parameters =ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(SCOPE)).build();
                // Try to acquire a token. If successful, you should see
                // the token information printed out to console
                result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
            } else {
                // Handle other exceptions accordingly
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.accessToken());
```

call graph api:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(httpResponseCode == HTTPResponse.SC_OK) {

            StringBuilder response;
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))){

                String inputLine;
                response = new StringBuilder();
                while (( inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
            }
            return response.toString();
        } else {
            return String.format("Connection returned HTTP code: %s with message: %s",
                    httpResponseCode, conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
```

error message:
Connection returned HTTP code: 400 with message: Bad Request

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/

same id success on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/

but , My program always reports errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's related to the request. It might work when we use `/users/userId` instead of `/me`. You can also test with `/users` to list all the users and see if it worked and validate if the token is correct.

[image]
[image]

I noticed that you had `ClientCredentialParameters` and you only used `CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET` to do the authentication whick matches the feature of client credential flow. Client credential flow doesn't require user to sign in to generate access token, so that we couldn't user `/me` in this scenario.

Comment: Or could you pls share the value of `SCOPE`? If you are using `xx/.default` then you are using client credential flow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/calendars

The browser's token can respond normally, but when I use my own token, it prompts me 404, which really confuses me.

Comment: could you pls use the token generated by your code along with request `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`?

Comment: my SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

Comment: you can take a look at the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), and you will find that the correct API url should be `/me/calendars` or `users/userid/calendars`, so getting 404 with `/users/calendars` might be the expected behavior.

Comment: The token generated by the code can be accessed https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

But I hope to be able to access https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/calendars

Comment: ok, that means your code already generated a correct token but the token might be lack of correct scope, could you pls copy and paste your token generated by your code to `jwt.io` and decode the token, then look at the values of claim `roles`, you can combine with the 2 tokens and see if they share different `roles`

Comment: we can also see the required api permission for calendar, it requires `Application Calendars.ReadBasic Calendars.ReadWrite, Calendars.Read` which doesn't have `xx.All` so that you can't read all users' calendar. Let's see the api url `/users` it will list all the users information which requires `User.Read.All and Directory.Read.All` API permission.